# AWS Neptune datetime()

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I'm using `gremlin-javascript` to talk to AWS Neptune from Node. According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html) and [quickstart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/quickstart.html), dates should be set using `datetime()`.

I did not find an implementation of this `datetime()` function in `gremlin`. Where should this be imported from?

`g.addV("user").property(single, "createdDate", datetime(now().toISOString());`

`"ReferenceError: datetime is not defined"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the 'datetime()' method that Neptune provides is intended to be used when sending queries to the graph as text Strings. Here is an example from the Gremlin console attached to a running Neptune instance:

```
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('timestamp',datetime('2018-11-04T00:00:00')).property(id,'t1')
==>v[t1]
gremlin> g.V('t1').valueMap()
==>{timestamp=[Sun Nov 04 00:00:00 UTC 2018]}
gremlin> g.V().has('timestamp',gt(datetime('2018-11-03T00:00:00')))
==>v[t1]
```

Now, if you are using a GLV language such as Gremlin Python you can use the native Python `datetime` class instead. As shown below. Note while the two examples share the name `datetime` they are completely different iin everything but name. I ran this from a Jupyter Notebook using Gremlin Python but it works equally well in the Python console or as a standalone Python app.

```
import datetime
g.addV('test').\
    property(id,'x2').\
    property('timestamp',datetime.datetime.now()).next()

v[x2]

g.V('x2').valueMap(True).next()

{<T.label: 3>: 'test',
 <T.id: 1>: 'x2',
 'timestamp': [datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 5, 15, 3, 52, 29000)]}
```

Please forgive a Python example - I know you are using Javascript. I just happened to have a Python environment configured but the same principles should apply.

All of this said as I and others have mentioned in other posts, I prefer to store timestamps using epoch time. Typically I use 10 or 13 digit integer representations of time depending upon the precision I need. This is also a fairly portable way to store time information and easy to test using greater than/less than predicates etc.

Anyway, I hope this helps clarify your choices a little bit.
Cheers, Kelvin.

UPDATED October 15th 2019
Specifically in the Neptune case, using the native date object from Java, Python etc. may result in queries that run a  little faster due to the way the Neptune Engine evaluates queries.

Comment: Note that internally, Neptune _is_ storing dates as epoch millis.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Does that mean everything gets stored as epoch millis internally ? Even if it is from 
   1. Gremlin console datetime()
   2. Or a GLV variant like Nodejs's or Python's native date time class.